# Visual Studio 2017 RC4: Console Output is gone

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I recently upgrade my VS2017 from RC3 to RC4.

Previously under the "Debug" section, when i launch as project there isnt `Web Server Settings` , however in RC4 its a required field. ( Refer to attached screenshot )

Also , previously when i run the project there will be a console popup where it shows all the output from "Debug" however in RC4 this console is also missing , is there any configuration or setting i should set?

[image]

Not avaliable

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can bring it out from the Debug Menu: Linux Console.